# count multiple row values separated by comma

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a MySQL DB with multiple rows and a column that contain some text, separated with comma.

For a quick idea, my DB look like this:

```
id | column
 1 |  aaa, bbb
 2 |  ccc, ddd, aaa
 3 |  eee, aaa, ccc
 4 |  ddd
```

Output need to be like this:

```
aaa - 3
bbb - 1
ccc - 2
ddd - 2
eee - 1
```

After I search all over the internet, I still don't know how to do it.
Please, be kind and give me some ideas to solve it.

Comment: Normalize the DB and this will be very easy to do. CSVs don't belong in columns. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: What you've tried so far??

Comment: If you can normalize the db then your life will be easy

Comment: Since your data is store like that, you will have to do a full table scan, read every value, do some regex on it, and store the count of each text in some variable (associative array would be a good idea here).  This is why you do NOT want to store CSV data in columns, like pointed out by chris85 (among other problems with inserting, data integrity, ...).

Comment: I know is a bad idea to store values with comma, but my app is already done. I cannot modify my DB structure. So, I need a way to count those values.

Comment: Then I suggest `select * from thetable` plus a loop and string examination in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a reason for your data structure and you are not willing you normalize the database then you will need to do this in PHP, however I strongly recommend normalization if there is not a reason.

```
// This will come from the query, but for the example
$array = Array("aaa, bbb", "ccc, ddd, aaa", "eee, aaa, ccc", "ddd");

// Initilize an empty array for holding count values
$counterArray = Array();

// Loop through each "table row"
foreach ($array as $row)
{
    // Split the row on the comma
    $splitRow = explode(',', $row);

    // Loop through each item found on the row
    foreach ($splitRow as $item)
    {      
        // Trim to get rid of any leading/trailing spaces
        $arrayKey = trim($item);

        // Check if the array contains the values already, if yes increment otherwise creaet a record with a initial value of 1
        if (!array_key_exists($arrayKey, $counterArray))
            $counterArray[$arrayKey] = 1;
        else
            $counterArray[$arrayKey]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// This will come from the query, but for the example
$array = Array("aaa, bbb", "ccc, ddd, aaa", "eee, aaa, ccc", "ddd");
print_r(array_count_values($array));

// you will get associative array with count.
```

Comment: i tried your example, but, i don't know why, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

It is no-brainer that **Normalizing** your database is the **best** solution here.
Also, as the other answers suggested, achieving the mentioned task **programmaticaly** will be a simple and efficient solution, too.

But if the above 2 options are not suitable for you at all, then following is the way to achieve it with **PL\SQL**.

**1)** If you only want to find the Number of occurrence of a **single word** at a time, you can try following way:

```
select
distinct
'aaa' as Word,
ROUND (   
        (
            CHAR_LENGTH(@str)
            - CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE (@str, 'aaa', "") ) //you can put the word here you want
        ) / CHAR_LENGTH('aaa')        
    ) AS count
    from t
   ;
```

**Result:**

```
    word | count
   --------------
    aaa  |  3
```

**2)** If you want to display the count of all the words as given in question, you need a **Function**, a **Procedure** and a **Temp Table**.

**Step 1:**  Create an **Temporary** table.

```
         create table temp(str varchar(10));
```

**Step 2:** Create a **Function** to **split** data with delimiter `,` with given position.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR
(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

Now, the above function will split data only for the given position. In order to split whole string,  we need to iterate this function. That's our step 3.

**Step 3:** Create Procedure to iterate the above function;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ABC(IN fullstr varchar(1000))
   BEGIN
      DECLARE a INT Default 0;
      DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);
      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET a=a+1;
         SET str=SPLIT_STR(fullstr,",",a);         
         IF str='' THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;       
         END IF;        
         #Do Inserts into temp table here with str going into the row
         insert into t1 values (str);
   END LOOP simple_loop;
```

**Step 4:** Store whole column into one variable:

```
select @str:= group_concat(columnname separator ',') from t;
```

**Step 5:** Call Procedure:

```
       call abc(@str);
```

**Step 6:** Get count from `temp` table:

```
select
str as word,
count(*) as occurence   
from temp
group by str;
```

**Results:**

```
        word  | occurence
   -------------------------
    1   aaa   |    3
    2   bbb   |    1
    3   ccc   |    2
    4   ddd   |    2
    5   eee   |    1
```

[Click here for the DEMO](http://rextester.com/TAYC39765)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please have a look at the answer as well as the Demo.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, guys.
Based on your ideas, I made a poorly script that do the job, without modify DB. My DB is already normalized, except one single column of one table(*witch was not designed to be used like in my example*). I will describe the script here, for further user who will need it.
My column can only contain between 0-5 predefined words, comma separated. 
For each word, I assigned a $var with his name. Then, in while loop from MySQL, i check if string contain that word. 
`if(strpos($domeniu,'Producator') !== false){$producator = $producator + $count_domeniu;}`. 
Repeat code for every word.
***Producator** is one word from that 5, predifined earlyer.*
***$producator** is $var defined 0, before while loop.*
***$count_domeniu** = $row['count_domeniu'];*
After the While loop, echo $producator var.
My mysql query is `("SELECT domeniu_activitate, COUNT(domeniu_activitate) as count_domeniu FROM tbl_expozanti GROUP BY domeniu_activitate")`.

Comment: Good that you found a solution that worked for you,but if you have only 5 different values and you can afford to count then separately as you did here,then the first approach in my answer will be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but while going through the same problem, I landed here also while searching for answers so others may also. Finally found the perfect answer for myself that will work for you too in a simple MySQL query way. So here is the simple query to count multiple row values separated by a comma.

As per your table, the data is structured somehow as...

```
id | column
 1 |  aaa, bbb
 2 |  ccc, ddd, aaa
 3 |  eee, aaa, ccc
 4 |  ddd
```

So to get your answer, just use the following query...

```
SELECT substring_index(column, ',', -1)  AS columnTextRenamed, COUNT(substring_index(column, ',', -1)) AS columnCountRenamed
FROM my_table_name
GROUP BY columnTextRenamed
ORDER BY columnTextRenamed;
```

And then this will output as...

```
columnTextRenamed | columnCountRenamed
aaa               |                  3
bbb               |                  1
ccc               |                  2
ddd               |                  2
eee               |                  1
```

And this is what you want.

Comment: This does not work: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cshxwqq7VyaudvV1WJmSSa/0